# NSMutableData to CConstPointer conversion in Swift needed

Tags: ios7, swift

The following Swift code (writing bytes to a stream) is rewritten from Objective-C:

```
var outputStream : NSOutputStream = NSOutputStream()
var pData : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
var pType : Int = 1
let pMessage : String = "Device_Description\0\0\x01" // 16BitChar with escapeSequence
var pLength : Int = 8+pMessage.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding)

pData.appendBytes(&pLength, length: 4)
pData.appendBytes(&pType, length: 4)
pData.appendData((pMessage as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding))

outputStream.write(pData.bytes, maxLength: pData.length)
```

`pData.bytes` is of type `COpaquePointer`, but `CConstPointer<Uint8>`is needed by the write operation. Any hints for the correct conversion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may need to reverse the logic entirely... first you should create a buffer with `CConstPointer<Uint8>` for your stream and then you can init your `NSData` passing that buffer to it. that logic is much closer to the _Swift_'s spirit than the way you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jack wu has outlined, but somewhat incompletely, the following code works just the same as using the UnsafePointer option:

```
var byteData = [UInt8]()
pData.getBytes(&byteData)
self.outputStream!.write(byteData, maxLength: pData.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Swift & Objc interop book section here : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

> C Constant Pointers
>
> When a function is declared as taking a CConstPointer argument,
>   it can accept any of the following:
>
> - nil, which is passed as a null pointer
> - A CMutablePointer, CMutableVoidPointer, CConstPointer,    CConstVoidPointer, or AutoreleasingUnsafePointer value, which
>     is converted to CConstPointer if necessary
> - An in-out expression whose operand is an lvalue of type Type, which    is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - A Type[] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the    array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

I believe then it can work like this:

```
var p: [Uint8] = []
pData.getBytes(&p)
outputStream.write(p, maxLength: pData.length)
```

Comment: _you think, guessing is your ally_? the presented 4 lines of code is full of syntax and logical errors....

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution right now, by use of `UnsafePointer<T>()`:

```
var outputStream : NSOutputStream = NSOutputStream()
var pData : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
var pType : Int = 1
let pMessage : String = "Device_Description\0\0\x01" // 16BitChar with escapeSequence
var pLength : Int = 8+pMessage.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding)

pData.appendBytes(&pLength, length: 4)
pData.appendBytes(&pType, length: 4)
pData.appendData(ptpMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding))

outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(pData.bytes), maxLength: pData.length)
```

@holex: Thanks for your input. I know this solution is not quite Swifty, but it´s working for now.